# The set of constant functions on $[0,1]$ is closed in $C^{1}([0,1])$ with the sup norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X= C^{1}([0,1])$ be the space of all continuously differentiable scalar valued functions on $[0,1]$ with the sup norm making it into a normed linear space. Then, the set of constant functions is closed in $X$.

I don't understand how to approach proving such a statement. Please help me prove it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the set of constant functions is a vector subspace of dimension $1$ (take the function $f(x)=1$ as a basis vector). Finite-dimensional subspaces are always closed.

Comment: nice!! thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Show that the complement is open. Take $f \in X= C^{1}([0,1])$ that is not constant, then there is $a, b$ such that $f(a) \neq f(b)$ so there is an open $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(f(b)-\epsilon,  f(b)+ \epsilon)$ does not contain $f(a)$. So take an open ball $B(f,\epsilon/2)$ centered in $f$. So for  $g \in B(f,\epsilon/2),\ |g(a)-f(a)|< \epsilon/2$, and $|g(b)-f(b)|< \epsilon/2$, so $g(a) \neq g(b)$, so the complement is open.

Comment: I fixed some spelling errors.